# while loop not executing with timer

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I'm pretty new to Swift, been practicing for about a week now. I've declared a timer, I call the function of the timer with `viewDidLoad()`, and the timers `#selector` points to `goldPerSec`, that function is a simple while loop, yet it's not executing every second as it should.

Here's my code:

```
var timer = Timer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    counter()
}

func counter() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.goldPerSec), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func goldPerSec() {
    while (totalOwned >= 1) {
        Gold += (minerOwned * 1)
        goldLabel.text = "\(Gold)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop in `goldPerSec` runs forever preventing any other code from running on the main queue, including the timer.

Change the `while` loop to an `if` statement.

```
@objc func goldPerSec() {
    if totalOwned >= 1 {
        Gold += minerOwned * 1
        goldLabel.text = "\(Gold)"
    }
}
```

This will now allow `goldPerSec` to be called every second from the timer and also allow the rest of your user interface to work.

As a side note, variable names should start with lowercase letters so `Gold` should be named `gold`.

Comment: As a 3 year back-end PHP developer, I'm embarrassed that I couldn't figure this out, this makes 110% sense. Thank you so much. Also, with the conditions in if's and while's, is it acceptable to write `if (totalOwned...)` with parenthesis? That's what I'm most familiar with and of course I'd do that all throughout my code to be consistent.

Comment: The parentheses are not required in Swift.

Comment: Will I run into any issues if I use parentheses? I personally feel more organized and find it easier to read when I use them.